# Memory Managing QByteArray::fromRawData()

Tags: c++, qt

In my program I have a function that processes some data and sends it back. In the function I allocate a new byte array with the following:

```
byte *buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
```

I then pass that to a library which fills it with some data. Once it's done, I want to send it back as a `QByteArray`. So I call:

```
myByteArray = QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer), bufferSize);
```

The byte array gets returned back and everything runs fine, however I now have a memory leak (pretty sure since my RAM usage skyrockets since I call this thousands of times). When I allocate `buffer` with new, I can't delete it after calling `fromRawData` because `myByteArray` shares the same data pointer. The [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qbytearray.html#fromRawData) states `The bytes are not copied. The QByteArray will contain the data pointer.`

So my question is, how can I ensure that `buffer` gets deleted when `myByteArray` goes out of scope? It goes out of scope in the class the function was called from.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: When creating from raw data you take responsibility for the memory management.

Comment: Responsibility accepted. I'm just unsure about the best way to handle this since my QByteArray gets sent around EVERYWHERE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually allocating the array with `new[]`, you can start directly with a `QByteArray`.

```
QByteArray myByteArray;
myByteArray.resize( bufferSize );
byte * buffer = myByteArray.data(); // Pointer to the memory allocated by the QByteArray
// Pass 'buffer' to library function..
```